# return array of objects in graphql rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

I need write code for show users with organizations, but return next error in query, search, but with error

My code

```
module Types
  class UserType < Types::BaseObject
    field :id, ID, null: false
    field :email, String, null: false
    field :role, String, null: true
    field :organization_ids, [Types::OrganizationType], null: false
  end
end

module Types
  class OrganizationType < Types::BaseObject
    field :id, ID, null: false
    field :name, String, null: false
  end
end
```

But return next error

[image]

This  is my query

[image]

Comment: maybe there is something wrong with this Types::OrganizationType], do you have other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to return an association: a User has many Organizations?

Make sure in `user.rb` you have the association defined with `has_many :organizations` ... and include any middle models required for Rails to understand the associations

Update your UserType to:

```rb
module Types
  class UserType < Types::BaseObject
    ...
    field :organizations, [Types::OrganizationType], null: false
  end
end
```

Then you should be able to query like:

```
query getUsers{
  users {
    id
    email
    role
    organizations {
      id
    }
  }
}
```